# Can we use springboot to authenticate for a nodejs application?

Tags: java, node.js, spring, spring-boot, authentication

Our application is built on NodeJS and I want to Authenticate/Authorize using Spring.

Is it possible to add spring service at start and redirect the authenticated users to NodeJs service?

**SpringAuthentication <--> nodeJs <--> DB**

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is very much possible.

You should expose an API of the Spring Application as the entry point for the NodeJs application and upon being authenticated the request is directed downstream(here NodeJs). This means the client is aware of the spring application API and not the NodeJs API application.

Here is a good [place](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html) to start.

Comment: Link does not work